# Is there a way to say capital letters?

Tags: pronunciation, capitalization

Say when I'm reciting a password to someone I say something like:

> capital a b capital c d capital e

Is there any way to pronounce upper case letters without having to say `capital` in front of the letter?

Comment: No! And it is even worse.  If you say "capital a b" it may be interpreted as "AB".  So: "capital a small b" is the best you can do.

Comment: By agreement with whomever you're talking to you could say the capital letters in a higher pitch, or raise a finger while saying those letters, etc., but there's no established system and no distinction in pronunciation.

Comment: You can say “Big A” or “Cap A” if *capital* is too many syllables.   You could also do things like it’s “abce, with the A, C and E all caps”